# Is it good to equalize input impedances in cascade active opamp filters?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, active-filter, high-pass-filter

In my design, I designed a first 2nd order high pass filter with a Sallen key cut-off frequency of 0.2Hz and an input impedance of 250kohm. Then, I designed a second-order Multiple-Feedback low pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 100 khz and its input impedance is 15kohm. Thus, I have a bandpass filter. I wonder if it is good to equalize the input impedance of both filters? What effects can different filter input impedances have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I wonder if it is good to equalize the input impedance of both
> filters? What effects can different filter input impedances have?*

For the frequencies you are talking about (100 kHz maximum), impedance matching (if that's what you mean) is pointless. You only impedance match when you are trying to: -

- Maximize power transfer (you aren't)
- Avoid disruptive signal reflections (you won't be at 100 kHz or probably even up to 10 MHz)

If you mean "make equal" the input impedances for both stages, that also doesn't matter because both those circuits are unrelated to each other in that respect.